# Reading XML attributes and text

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7.5 app and I'm lost.

I have to read the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cards>
  <card id ="0">
    <name lang="en">Mad</name>
    <description lang="en">This...</description>
  </card>
...
</cards>
```

And I'm have to finish this piece of code:

```
private void UpdateCardDescriptions(int[] numbers, string lang)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Data/CardDescriptions.xml");

        reader.MoveToContent();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && 
                (reader.Name == "card") &&
                (reader.GetAttribute("id").Equals(numbers[i].ToString())))
            {
                string description = string.Empty;
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                }

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Card01Desc.Text = description;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Card02Desc.Text = description;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Card03Desc.Text = description;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name == "cards")
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

I have to finish this code:

```
while (reader.Read())
{

}
```

If I'm looking for a description **in a language**, lang, for a card with an id. How can I get the corresponding description for the same language, lang.

I'm sorry, I'm blocked.

Comment: Any reason you're using `XmlReader` instead of the *much* simpler LINQ to XML API?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason: I am an ignorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used `XElement`, it's easy and widely supported by Windows Phone SDK.

```
private void UpdateCardDescriptions(int[] numbers, string lang)
{
    XElement xe = XElement.Load(yourXml);
    Control[] controls = new[] { Card01Desc, Card02Desc, Card03Desc };

    foreach(var number in numbers)
    {
        var card = xe.Desendants("card").Where(c => c.Attribute("id").Value == number)
                                        .First();

        ((YourControlType)controls[number]).Text = card.Desendants("description")
                                                    .Where(c => c.Attribute("lang").Value == lang)
                                                    .First()
                                                    .Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't check your answer as valid because that code doesn't compile and for statement is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled `Descendants`, I have updated the code now... Also please mind that `(YourControlType)` to be your control that you are using i.e. `TextBox`

Comment: In your answer, you have forgotten language: If I'm looking for a description in a **language**, lang, for a card with an id.

Comment: You mean, you want `lang="en"` to be present along with `<card id ="0">`?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve a card name and description in a specific language.

Comment: I have updated the code, this should be your replacement method from your post

Answer (score 3):

There is a more elegant approach:

```
XElement xmlCards = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

var cards = from card in xmlCards.Descendants("card")
select new CardItem
{
    ID = card.Attribute("id").Value,
    Name = card.Element("name").Value,
    Desciption = card.Element("description").Value
};
```

And now 'cards' will contain all your cards

(CardItem is just your card implementation)